# How to run Junit / TestNG tests based on an external input?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, testng, junit4

I have an Excel file where I am storing the Test case Name / Id.

Now, If my Test case name(in excel) is starting with 'test' I want to execute one of my Junit / TestNG test . If my test case name(in excel) is starting with 'check', I want to execute another Junit / TestNG test. And similarly, I want to execute different tests based on Ids in the excel.

How would I be able to do this?
Can some one please post an example which can be of great help to me.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I can read from Excel - No problem in here. How would I use this data in run time to chose the correct test method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want to do is dynamically build tests based on your excel sheet.
This is how you can run testng [programmatically](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html).

What you would need to do is read from your excel, create XmlClass and set the methods for xmlclass based on the testnames of your methods.  Add the xmlclass to XmlSuite.
So basically you are generating a dynamic suite at runtime based on the testcase names in your excel.

Comment: We can do this at class level.. Is there a way that we can do it at method level?  Each of my test class contains several testmethods..

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is something called reflection. In your xml you will have the class and method name of what you want to run. In java you'll then use reflection to grab the class, and iterate over the methods to determine if any match what you want. Reflection is generally not an efficient way of doing things, but for the purpose of testing it can do what you want.

An example would be

```
for(Method method : this.getClass().getMethods()){
{
    if(method.getName().equals(name)){
         method.invoke();
    }
}
```

Please read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/index.html for details.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar using testNG. My requirement was to run the test case which a user will select from a list of test cases. I was using Jenkins instead of excel sheet to let user select the test case from the list. Logic might work for you as well. Here is it:

Rather than figuring out which method to run, I gave a unique test group name to all test cases. This group name should be same as what you have in excel sheet. The only logic required would be to create the testng.xml to run the tests with the input group name. This can be done  using testNG objects or by creating an tesNG.xml using dom4j or something similar.